# Android SQLLite, Syntax error when trying to get data from single database column

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

im using the following code inside my DBAdapter.java file to select the values from a single column

```
// Get make column from DB
public Cursor getMakeCol() {
    String selectCol = "SELECT KEY_MAKE FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_MAKE}, selectCol, null,
            null,null,null,null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

this is how im trying to use getMakeCol from inside main.java

```
// Display make recordset from database inside textview
private void displayMake(Cursor cursor) {
    String message = "";
    // populate the message from the cursor

    // Reset cursor to start, checking to see if there's data:
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String make = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_MAKE);
            // Append data to the message:
            message += "Make: " + make + "\n";
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
    // Close the cursor to avoid a resource leak.
    cursor.close();
    displayText(message);
}
```

this is activated by an onClick event and then displayed inside a textview

```
// display column data
public void btnGetColClick(View v) {
    Cursor cursor = myDb.getMakeCol();
    displayMake(cursor);
}
```

however when im debugging the application and i activate the onClick event logcat displays the following

```
07-25 16:11:58.300: E/SQLiteLog(1738): (1) near "SELECT": syntax error
```

Are there any errors in the above code, can someone please explain why its not doing what i need.

Thank you

Comment: -1 for not reading docs ... `selection - A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given table.`

Comment: Why you are passing entire query there for third param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using `db.query` in wrong way

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_MAKE}, null, null, null);
```

should be equal to `SELECT KEY_MAKE FROM DATABASE_TABLE`

if you want to filter the table, use the third parameter for the where clause

```
String whereClause = "id=? AND group_id=?";
String[] args = new String[]{"1", "2"}; //some example data
Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_MAKE}, whereClause, args, null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, i also realised i wasnt returning rowId either which was also causing me an issue.